# Problem with MySQL's LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

I am having a problem with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Every time I use it I need to open and close a new connection. 
This slows down my application a great deal.
i need to do many insert statements end get for each one his inserted id
all on the same connection!
How can I get the last inserted ID on the same connection
for with MySQl, ODBC and C# from a specific table with no concurrency problems?

here is my code:

```
#region Private Variables
private static DataAccess _DataAccess = null;
private static object _SyncLock = new object();
private OdbcConnection myConnection = null;
#endregion

#region Instance Method
public static DataAccess Instance
{
    get
    {
        lock (_SyncLock)
        {
            if (_DataAccess == null)
                _DataAccess = new DataAccess();
            return _DataAccess;
        }
    }
}
#endregion

#region Constractors
public DataAccess()
{
    myConnection = new OdbcConnection(stringConnDB);
    myConnection.Open();
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 4):

> Every time I use it i need to open and close a new connection

No, you don't need a new connection. You are supposed to use it on the same connection just after an insert statement.

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html):

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a *per-connection basis*. This means that the value returned by [`LAST_INSERT_ID`] to a given client is the first `AUTO_INCREMENT` value generated for most recent statement affecting an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by *that client*. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate `AUTO_INCREMENT` values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

Comment: mysql teem say very claerly: "The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis" - every client have is on connection thats the way they make sure no other client will effect other client - for each client a new connection - very bed for me... or mybe i am worng?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think that you need to open a new connection? Actually you should *not* open a new connection, you should use `last_insert_id()` on the same connection to be sure to get the correct result.

If you have tried it with a new connection and it seems to work, then it's only because the connections are pooled, and you happen to get the same connection the second time. When you start to use this with more than one single user, it will fail.

Comment: but i do not understand thay say:"The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis" - isnt it meen for every client a new connection in order that every client will get his last insert id without disturb from other client?

Comment: @user374290: No, it means the opposite. You *have to* use the same connection for the insert as when you get the id to be sure that it's correct. If you open a new connection the id will either be empty, or if the connection was pooled, an id from any random insert that was done before. That random insert may be the one that you just did, but it could just as well be some other insert.

Comment: It's obvious that I use the same connection for the insert and the SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() that came right after. thats totaly not what i am talking about! for every time i am doing those tow i have to open a new connection and thats very very bed - i will show here the code i am using

Comment: i edited my question so you cen see my code and understand my problam

Comment: @user374290: There is no reason why running a specific query would keep you from reusing the connection. You may get that effect if you don't close a command or data reader properly, so that they are still using the connection when you try to use it for the next command. Also your code has commands for synchronisation, but that is not needed. Each thread should have it's own connection, so your variables should not be static. If you try to use the same connection from two threads at the same time, you will get errors.

Comment: synchronisation is needed i dont what Each thread to have it's own connection it is working better that way - but i do get errors on last insert id - so i guess i will use MAX(ID) with some conditions to make it accurate as much as i can